# List with fetch parameter

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a class called `Address` which has a boolean field called `clone`.  I am trying to use the Grails `list()` method to show instance of the `Address` class where `clone = false`.  I though I could use the `fetch` parameter to accomplish this, but it is not working as expected.  Instead of returning only the addresses I want it returns all instances of the `Address` class.  Here is what I have:

```
def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    params.fetch = [clone:false]
    [addressInstanceList: Address.list(params), addressInstanceTotal: Address.count()]
}
```

Even when I make it really simple fetch still does not work as expected.  For example if I specify that I just want to fetch instances of the `Address` class with the zip code "90210" I wrote this, but it still gives me all instances of the `Address` class.

```
Address.list(fetch:[zip:"90210"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fetch` parameter for the `Domain.list()` method is not for filtering the response or just fetching some items, it is for specifying whether properties of the Domain class are loaded eagerly or lazily

ie (from the [documentation for list](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html)):

```
def results = Book.list(fetch:[authors:"eager"])
```

To do what you are doing, I believe you could use a `findAllWhere` call, such as:

```
Address.findAllWhere( clone:false, zip:'90210' )
```

Comment: Haha, I actually did read the documentation (at 4am) but I was reading it like `eager` was the authors name! Thanks for the clarification, it all makes sense now.